# RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My situation is simple. I have one RecyclerView and inside it is a few other RecyclerViews. The internal RecyclerViews do not scroll when I try to scroll them.

Why is this? Is there a workaround?

Root XML with root RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.boxed.v2.ui.category.SortAndFilterView android:id="@+id/sortfilterview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    app:contentViewId="@+id/content"
    app:progressViewId="@+id/progressbar"
    app:secondaryViewId="@+id/error">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/bright_teal"
            android:text="Sort &amp; Filters"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            app:fontName="@string/font_sofia_medium"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.boxed.v2.ui.category.SortAndFilterView>
```

Then, nested item view containing nested RecyclerView (one of these per row in the root RecyclerView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/textlines"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:height="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fontName="@string/font_sofia_medium"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsable_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/embedded_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textlines"
            ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share XML layouts

Comment: Ok , Ive done this.

Answer (score 0):

The LayoutManager gets Confused on which View to scroll,
To make the inner RV to scroll do this.

Create a NestedScrollView inside the Top RV

Then inside the NestedScrollView Put your second RV

NB
RV = recyvlerView

Comment: It seems like this only works if the NestedScrollView has height match_parent. Is there a way to give it a shorter height and still scroll correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For a RecyclerView to scroll, one of two things must be true:

- The RecyclerView has a smaller height than all of its items
- The RecyclerView is inside a scrolling parent

  In your case embedded_recycler_view height must be less then collapsable_content ( you have use match_parent and that is wrong) or you add another scrollview inside collapsable_content and then added embedded_recycle

then
set setHasFixedSize to true and  also set setRecycledViewPool for child

Comment: What is recycledViewPool?

Comment: to optimize recycleview performance  in case of nested  recycleview

refer this :
https://proandroiddev.com/optimizing-nested-recyclerview-a9b7830a4ba7

Comment: Ok thanks for that tip. Still experiencing the original issue though.

Comment: For a RecyclerView to scroll, one of two things must be true:

The RecyclerView has a smaller height than all of its items
The RecyclerView is inside a scrolling parent

In your case embedded_recycler_view height must be less then collapsable_content ( you have use match_parent and that is wrong)

or you add another scrollview inside collapsable_content  and then added embedde_recycle

Comment: I have followed all of your advice and still it does not scroll. I want the embedded recycler view to be 200dp in height and scroll.